# passing click event to underlying view

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, android-layout

I have a Layout with a `TextView`. The `TextView` has

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

How can I achieve the following:

- if user clicks a link, an action associated with that link is executed (i.e., click on phone number invokes dialer, etc.)
- if user clicks anywhere else within Layout boundaries, Layout's onClick is called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an oclicklistener to the TextBox layout, and handle it from there.

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextBoxId));  
txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
                public void onClick(View view) {  

                  // USer Clicked the textBox  

                } 
       });
```

The same apply for the Layout, find it and ...

```
     layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
                public void onClick(View view) {  

                  // USer Clicked the layout  

                } 
       });
```

I hope it helps.